# Consult depending of params

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to make a generic query with all parameters and return the result? Instead of doing a query for each combination of parameters.

Example: color, height, width. Select by color, height, width, color and width, color and height ... in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any details about your data types, I'll assuming they are strings or some kind of enumerated values. A parameterized query like this would probably work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `color` LIKE :color
AND `height` LIKE :height
AND `width` LIKE :width;
```

And you'd bind different combinations for the results:

Select all blue things

```
:color = "blue"
:height = "%"
:width = "%"
```

Select all tall things

```
:color = "%"
:height = "tall"
:width = "%"
```

Select all tall, blue things

```
:color = "blue"
:height = "tall"
:width = "%%"
```

And so on. The `%` value in a `LIKE` clause means `LIKE any number of characters`.